# PI Zero W Mass storage device mode

Tags: usb, samba, storage

I need some help regarding the mass storage mode with Raspberry PI Zero W.
This is my first time configuring this mode and I've found a lot of guides about it that only explain how to use the PI as read only device plugged, for istance, into a TV to upload various video files from PC using Samba.

It's not very clear to me if it's possible to use this functionality to write data from an external machine into the PI, and that's my problem.. I'll explain my situation:

I have an industrial machine that only allows me to save logs into a USB device, but I need to write them into a different machine inside our network using Samba (this industrial machine has no Ethernet port or access to WiFi, so I cannot write these logs using network protocols/applications.. My only resource is the USB port that this machine offers).

Can I configure the mass storage mode of the PI Zero W so that it is possible to write data from our machine into the Raspberry and then use Samba to upload the logs?

It's not very clear if this mode allows you to write data into the PI as USB device (I've seen other questions about this, but all cases are different so I'm trying to get an answer for mine).
Anybody else ever tried this or knows if this can work?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Comment: Interesting question. I don't know the answer offhand. I did a [search using the title of your question](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffnt&q=PI+Zero+W+Mass+storage+device+mode&ia=web). Your question is at the top of the list (Congratulations - you've made the "front page"!). Have you read through any of these for an answer?

Comment: @Seamus Oh wow! didn't even notice that! I've read a lot of guides/forums that explains how to implement the solution but in read-only mode. The best answer has been given to me on another [forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=295364). (unfortunately it's not positive because this solution can't be used, but the explanation it's very clear!).